# Individual DataGrid Row Visibility

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF `DataGrid` bound to a collection of `Entity Framework` objects that's inside a parent EF object. Something along the lines of:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCustomer.Orders}" />
```

Now when I want to "delete" an Order, I don't want to actually delete it from the data source, I simply want to set its `IsDeleted` property to true so the data is retained.

My question is: how can I get my `DataGrid` to skip a row if it's `IsDeleted` property is true? I would really like to use binding and not codebehind. Something like this would be wonderful:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCustomer.Orders}" RowVisibilityPath="IsDeleted" />
```

Kind of along the lines of `DisplayMemberPath`. I realize I would need to convert the state of `IsDeleted`, but that's a different topic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just wrap the collection and remove it from the wrapper. Everything else is too complex. Shouldn't be a problem with a proper view model.

Answer (score 27):

Aside from using a CollectionView as mentioned you can do this via the RowStyle:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDeleted}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
       <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsDeleted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>                                     
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Much simpler approach than using the DataTrigger.

Comment: This one works for me than DataTrigger. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [CollectionView](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html) to [filter](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html#filtering) your data.

Comment: Could you provide some example, please?

Comment: @ClarkKent: I think [this blog post](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html) is a good tutorial, and has downloadable source too.