# Is it possible to hide rows according to some condition?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

I have a DataGrid that binding an `ObservableCollection` of self tracking entities

Users can "delete" records in the DataGrid, however the items don't actually get deleted from the database.

How can I only display rows that aren't marked as deleted?

I am using MVVM pattern.

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a little bit more information then you're after, but I was met with the exact same case and chose to display rows as greyed out, or 'redded' out when their state is toggled to deleted. You trigger properties and style target type might be a little different since I'm using an Xceed DataGrid and you're using the built-in Datagrid, but it'll be essentially the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10431650/529618

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataRow}" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ObjectState}" 
                     Value="{x:Static Member=objectmodel:EnumObjectState.Deleted}" >
            <!-- You can do anything in this trigger such as hide, collapse, or disable the row. I chose to apply a custom effect. -->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEED5D2"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="This entry will be permanently deleted the next time you save."/>
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ui:ColourAdjustEffect Saturation="0" Gamma="0.6" BrightnessAdjustment="-0.2" RedAdjustment="0.04" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

For what it looks like, check out the last 3 images in the combined image below:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx).Filter technique. Its very MVVM oriented.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `DataGrid.RowStyle`, you could use `DataTriggers` to set the `Visibility` to `Collapsed` or change the `Background` ([code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928716/546730)).

Comment: wouldnt it make the scrolling of the datagrid slower for seemingly complex templates? Plus Alternating-Row-Styles would screw the alternate backcoloring of the rows if intermediate rows hide.

Comment: @AngelWPF: I don't know, it is possible though that collapsed controls are optimized. Alternating colouring was not mentioned so i saw no need to consider it.